# Does Android come with a built-in plain text editor?

Tags: text-editor

I need to edit a simple plain text file. Is there a built-in text editor that comes with Android? I have Android 7, LG Stylo 3.

I just need to open a text file, and enter some words:
cat
dog
etc

I need to edit text, then share it via email or have it saved in Android file system so I can share it later.

Second question: if there is no such a thing, what is the simplest plain text editor app available for such task?

Comment: No Stock Android does not to my knowledge.  This should really be on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: We don't do software recommendations here. But be welcome to check my corresponding app listings: [Office Suites and Text Editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office) and, maybe, [Notes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes).

Answer (score 1):

**No** AFAICT, unless it it is preinstalled by the device manufacturer, for example some devices like Xiaomi, Huawei come with a preinstalled document editor (WPS), which not allows you to view but to edit text files as well.

As suggested above, stock android only comes with with text **viewer** , not editor, in any case if you need to install it, please see Izzy's list of suggested text editors

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm on Lenovo k8 note right now which is running stock Android 8.0. I was looking if it has some built-in text editor like vi in unix based systems.  I installed terminal emulator and looked for vi, vim and nano but got no luck. Then I tried sed(Stream EDitor) which also comes preinstalled with most unix based systems, and it worked well. So, yeah you can use sed to do some command line text manipulation.

Comment: This does not answer the question. On Android you have no command line. You should delete this wrong answer.